# how to manage vue reactivity?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to update a component after getting data from the data base.
but i get an error message. i have tried v-if and v-show and i had the same result.

the componenet that i want to update is a [modal](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal)

```
<div>
  <b-modal id="modal-xl"
           ok-title="next"
           :size="modalSize"
           @ok.prevent="launchContentModal"
           @cancel="resetPostModal"
           hide-header-close
           no-close-on-backdrop>
              <add-post :postTitle="postTitle" 
                        :postTopic="postTopic" 
                        :postType="postType">
              </add-post>
              <add-content v-show="post.id" 
                           :postType="postType">
              </add-content>
              <ArticlesEditor v-show=" post.id && post.postType.id"> 
              </ArticlesEditor>
    </b-modal>
</div>
```

and data object is :

```
        data(){
            return {
                postTitle:'',
                topic:'',
                postTopic:[],
                postType: {title: 'video',id:1},
                user:{},
                post:{
                    id:'',
                    postTopic:[],
                    postType:{
                        title:'',
                        id:'',
                    },
                },

            }
```

the request method  is :

```
launchContentModal(){
    if(!this.postTitle) this.$root.$emit('noTitleProvided');
    else if(!this.postTopic[0]) this.$root.$emit('noTopicProvided');
    else {
      this.post = { title: this.postTitle, topics:this.postTopic, type: this.postType};
      ResourceCenter.save(this.department, this.user, this.post)
      .catch(({response}) =>alert(response.data))
      .then(({data}) => {
           this.post = data;
       });
    }
},
```

after sending  save request ,i get the response correctly,
this is the response object:

````
{"title":"sdf","client_id":"12","department_id":"327","type":"ebook","type_id":2,"user_id":668,"updated_at":"2019-05-08 09:15:44","created_at":"2019-05-08 09:15:44","id":59} ```
````

and post object after getting the response updates correctly:

```
post:{"title":"sdf","client_id":"12","department_id":"327","type":"ebook","type_id":2,"user_id":668,"updated_at":"2019-05-08 09:15:44","created_at":"2019-05-08 09:15:44","id":59}
```

the expected result : modal should be updated and add-content compoenet should be showed.

the error message is :
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

i hope the explanation was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `post.postType` in your response but you are accessing `post.postType.id` from the template:

```
<ArticlesEditor v-show=" post.id && post.postType.id">
```

Here, `post.postType = undefined` & trying to access `post.postType.id` so, the error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"